# Is the pushforward of a flat modules flat

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, coherent-sheaves, flatness

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Let $X, Y, Z$ be $k$-schemes of finite type. Let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X \times Y \times Z$, flat over $Y \times Z$. Is $\mathrm{pr}_{23_*}F$ flat over $Z$, where $\mathrm{pr}_{23}:X \times Y \times Z \to Y \times Z$ is the natural projection map?

Comment: I think you must at least recognize that you could write $Y\times Z=T$ and $Y,Z$ do not play any individual roles. This is false in general and not difficult to construct examples. I suggest you look at the case of $X$ a smooth curve, $T=\mathrm{Pic}^{2g-2} X$, where $g\geq 2$, the genus of $X$ with the Poincare line bundle.

Comment: @Mohan What is $Z$ in this case? Just to be clear I am not asking if $\mathrm{pr}_{23_*}F$ is flat as a $Y \times Z$-module.

Comment: As I said, $Y,Z$ do not play any separate roles here. So, to go from $T$ to $Y\times Z$, you can simply take $T=Y\times Z$, since $T$ was arbitrary.